# R: Adding Numbers Without Built-In Functions

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

This is a question I have always wondered about.

Normally, when I want to add numbers in R, I use the built-in  `+` function:

```
> 5+10
[1] 15
```

**I have always been curious - how exactly is R doing this?**

I tried to find more information about this built-in function:

```
> getAnywhere("+")
A single object matching ‘+’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:base
  namespace:base
with value

function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("+")
```

But this does not seem to display any meaningful information about the `"+"` function.

As such, is it possible to add numbers in R without using `+`? For instance, is it possible to write a function in R that adds number such that `+` will not be defined at all?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `sum()`?

Comment: @benson23: thank you so much for your answer! without sum() as well... some natural way to do this?

Comment: Addition has nothing to do with R. the addition is done by the ALU. These are the basics of operations in computers. They are hardware coded and has nothing to do with the software

Comment: @jay.sf This question has nothing to do with the source code. OP is interested in adding two numbers. But there is no source code for that as addition is done by ALU and not softwares

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)

Comment: @Onyambu From the canonical, OP can derive `pryr::show_c_source(.Primitive("+"))` and will end up at the desired information, the [C source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed51d34ec195b89462a8531b9ef30b7b72e47204/src/main/eval.c#L5017), that clearly shows a `+` (that of C) involved. Eventually, of course, addition is done by the ALU, I've extended canonicals accorcdingly, thanks.